# Pushing apks from compiled AOSP to device

Tags: android, android-source

I synced code from AOSP onto my computer, modified the source for the `Phone.apk` file. I ran make (for Maguro), and got a Phone.apk file back in the /out folder. I'm using an AOSP rom on my phone (but not the one that I compiled myself), but when I move the created `Phone.apk` file into `/system/app` I lose signal, and when I launch `Settings > Mobile Networks` I get a FC. Logcat says I'm missing `MobileNetworkSettings.java` (which I know that I'm not). What do I need to do in order to use the apk files that I built from the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, I guess, is the following. Phone application uses sharedUserId: `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.phone"`. So as the AOSP image and your Phone.apk are signed with different certificates your Phone application is not allowed to receive this shared UID (because applications can share the same UID if they are signed with the same certificate) and receives a new UID. Thus, Phone application cannot work with radio interface (loose signal) and cannot be configured.

Try to create your AOSP image using your keys and flash it on the device. Then sign your Phone application with the same certificate. I guess this should help. Good luck!